# Create Office 2010 installer with SP1 and SP2 embedded

Tags: microsoft-office-2010, slipstream

I am creating new images for the PCs at my work, and using their disks, I'm finding that I still need to manually install SP1 and SP2 for Microsoft Office 2010. I downloaded the full, offline installers from Microsoft ([x86](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=39667), [x64](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=39647)), and currently have them on the file server, and I'm installing it manually. Yes, I understand I can wait to download it multiple times off of the Windows Update server, but what I'd ideally like is to slipstream SP1 and SP2 into my Office 2010 installation media. **Is this possible? If so, how?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a [website](http://www.howto-outlook.com/otherprograms/slipstreamo2k10sp.htm) with the answer. To summarize:

> Create the following folder structure:
>
> ```
> C:\Office2010\  
> C:\Office2010\DVD\  
> C:\Office2010\SP2\  
> C:\Office2010\SP2\extract\
> ```
>
> Extract the SP2 files (link in question) to the SP2\extract folder.
>
> Execute `"C:\Office2010\SP2\officesuite2010sp2-kb2687455-x86-fullfile-en-us.exe" /extract:"C:\Office2010\SP2\extract"` from the Administrative Command Line
>
> Accept the EULA
>
> Insert your Office 2010, and copy the contents to the `Office2010\DVD` folder
>
> Copy all the files from the `C:\Office2010\SP2\extract\` to the `Updates` folder in
>   `C:\Office2010\DVD\`

You can then burn the DVD, or run the `setup.exe` file to install it at the Service Pack 2 level